# How to insert a HTML string data into MySQL using javascript and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Using jQuery I can generate a string like this on a HTML document :

```
num0=500356,num1=853734,num2=981608,num3=795915,num4=824111,num5=831158,num6=364091,num7=368537,num8=410001
```

This data is not in a form or input HTML tag. It is a string assigned to a variable.

Is there a way to capture this string using javascript and PHP and then insert the numX into a mysql db such as? The db will have fields of num0, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8

```
num0=500356
num1=853734
num2=981608
num3=795915
num4=824111
num5=831158
num6=364091
num7=368537
num8=410001
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: your question si way too open ended and it doesn't deal with a problem but a lack of skill to do it. you should consider clarifying a little more. Altho people can and will help you with this matter no one will solve it for you. so make sure you have the necessary skills to produce the anser based on the help provided.

Comment: Where in the document is this string? If it is free-floating, do you mean it is just text (such as in a `<p>` tag)? Do you need to retrieve it from the document first, or can we assume that it can be read easily and you just need to know how to process it?

Comment: @halfer, it can be generated so it is assigned to a variable. Yes, it can be placed in a <div> or <p> tag.

Comment: Assigned to a JS variable? OK, convert it into a PHP array and do `var myJsArray = <?php echo json_encode($myPhpArray) ?>;` in your HTML output, inside a `<script>` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ar = explode("=", $var);
$ar[0] // num0
$ar[1] // 500356
$ar[2] // num1
$ar[3] // 853734
```

Comment: No, exploding on `=` will give you `num0`, `500356,num1`, `853734,num2` etc - probably not what you want! The trick is to explode on the comma first, and then for each pair (`num0=500356`), explode on the `=` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

If the document is in your server you can just make an ajax call when this parameters are available and insert it to your database using php.

If they are on another server you just need to make a php script to fetch em and insert.

Comment: Hi, ok, I figured out how to do it in a new way, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure but you can try this .

```
$str = explode(",","num0=500356,num1=853734,num2=981608,num3=795915,num4=824111,num5=831158,num6=364091,num7=368537,num8=410001");

foreach($str as $s){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($s);
}
```

It would be output something like this.

```
num0=500356
num1=853734
num2=981608
num3=795915
num4=824111
num5=831158
num6=364091
num7=368537
num8=410001
```